# Enable opcache for locally developed Laravel projects in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, phpstorm, opcache

How would I locally enable opcache while developing in a Laravel project within PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open **Run** -> **Edit Configurations**
2. Create a new configuration by expanding **Defaults**, then select **PHP Built-in Web Server**
3. Set the following values:

   - Host: *localhost*
   - Port: *80*
   - Document root: *select the public folder in the project*
   - Check *Use router script:* and select `server.php` in Laravel's project root directory
   - Interpreter options: `-d zend_extension=php_opcache.dll -d opcache.enable_cli=1 -d opcache.memory_consumption=128 -d opcache.max_accelerated_files=10000 -d opcache.validate_timestamps=0 -d opcache.save_comments=0`
4. Ensure that you have entered an appropriate name for the configuration (ex. **Local - with opcache**)
5. Click **Ok**

This will cache the PHP scripts when the program is being executed.  No invalidation for re-caching occurs with the current configuration.  So, now [file watchers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html) are needed to detect when changes are made.

1. Open **File** -> **Settings**
2. Navigate to **Tools** -> **File Watchers**
3. Add a new watcher by clicking on the green plus symbol (**+**) and select `<custom>`
4. From the **File type** drop-down list, select **PHP** and set the following values:

   - Scope: *Project Files*
   - Program: `php`

     - This will already need to be set in your machine's path environment or you'll need to set the exact file path
   - Arguments: `-d zend_extension=php_opcache.dll -d opcache.enable_cli=1 -r "opcache_reset();"`
   - Expand **Advanced Options** and make sure all checkboxes are **UNCHECKED**
   - All other default values should sufficient
5. Set a descriptive name for the watcher and click **Ok**

This watcher will now detect any changes made to PHP files in your project when a manual save is invoked and invalidate the entire cache to be rebuilt.

For blades, repeat the exact same steps immediately above.  However, select **Blade** as the **File type** (obviously).  This ensures those changes are also reflected while developing locally.

### Note

- This directly replaces the usage of `php artisan serve [--port=80]`
- This assumes that the php_opcache.dll file already exists in your `PHP/ext` folder.  Otherwise, refer to the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.installation.php) to get it installed.
- These instructions were developed on a Windows environment.  However, I'm sure they'd be easily ported over to other OS environments as well.

Comment: 1) Why do you need all this? I think it's better to not to have it enabled for local dev  2) Why not enable it all in php.ini for whole local PHP installation? or perhaps using custom config file (if that's possible)? 3) You can use single File Watcher, just create custom scope that would include all desired files and then use that instead of default stuff (you will see what I mean when you try it)

Comment: @LazyOne 1) Because some of the Laravel projects I work in are massive and I can notice the speed gain from using this. 2) I wanted to keep the opcache disabled by default to avoid conflicting configurations with other projects; which is also useful when I switch to other run configurations (like enabling xdebug locally).  3) Good to know.  I'll update the answer in that case.

Comment: @LazyOne follow-up to #3:  After looking at what you were talking about - **I'm** going to avoid your suggestion, because after looking at my layout of watchers, I'd like to be able to activate/deactivate a watcher per file type.  I do think your point is still valid, though.  If it can be done and that's what's desired, go for it.  I want it separated out, though.